# How to get binary data as a vector<complex> in C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to read binary data and put them in the vector from the file written as:

```
std::ofstream outfile1("channel_1.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
//...
outfile1.write((const char*)&buff1.front(), nwrite * sizeof(complex<short>));
```

I wrote the code to read that file:

```
int main(){
    double total_bytes, vector_size;
    streampos begin,end;
    std::ifstream ifs("channel_1.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    begin           = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg (0, ios::end);
    end             = ifs.tellg();
    total_bytes     = end - begin; // 320MB, 32e7 
    vector_size     = total_bytes/ sizeof(complex<short>);  // 8e7
    std::vector<std::complex<float> > v(vector_size);
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data()), vector_size*sizeof(complex<short>));
    ifs.close();

    for(int i=0;i<vector_size; i++){
        std::cout <<i << v[i]<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

but I still get zeros for all the complex vector, about 8e7 samples:

```
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
(0,0)
...
```

I used the same file in the matlab and it worked. Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: @Sergey I hope you can help me?

Comment: v elements are of type `std::complex<float>`, the write (and the read) are of  type `std::complex<short>`.  That's not going to work.  You will have to read the `std::complex<short>` into a buffer, and then convert.  (You could do a few thousand at a time for efficiency).

Comment: Note that `sizeof(short)` is typically 2 (and hence `sizeof(complex<short>)` is 4, whereas `sizeof(float)` is typically 4 (and hence the complex is size 8).

Comment: @MartinBonner Thanks for pointing me the error, but after a adjusted it, and it still giving me a zero vector complex(0,0) (0,0) (0,0) .... (0,0) (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

std::vector buf(N / sizeof(double));// reserve space for N/8 doubles
infile.read(reinterpret_cast(buf.data()), buf.size()*sizeof(double)); // or &buf[0] for C++98

Assuming the entire file is double, otherwise this wont work properly.
Use this format.. i hope it will work

Comment: @ Saikat Bhandary @ Saikat Bhandary: is it the same when I am working on the vector complex?

Answer (score 0):

`short` is a signed platform-dependent integer type. On my machine it's 2 bytes long. `float` is a floating point type 4-bytes long. Moreover, floating point types on modern machines (including x86) are fundamentally different from integer types, they also are [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32). So you can't just take a set of 2-byte integer numbers in it's binary representation and put them into `float`s. If you do so, you'll get garbage in the floating point variables instead of the data you wanted.

So a correct variant is to declare a compatible storage:

```
std::vector<std::complex<short>> vs(vector_size);
```

read data into it:

```
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vs.data()), vector_size*sizeof(complex<short>));
```

and then copy the data to a vector of floating point complex:

```
std::vector<std::complex<float> > v(vector_size);
std::copy(vs.begin(), vs.end(), v.begin());
```

`std::copy` in this case will use assignment operator of `std::complex`, which handles `short`->`float` cast of underlying data correctly.

And the last but not the least. You called

```
ifs.seekg(0, ios::end);
```

so now your file cursor stands at the end of the file, and any read attempt will read nothing, leaving `vs` untouched. I suppose you build a debug version, so `vs` initially holds zeros. And you get them untouched after `ifs.read` call. To get you data from the file, please call

```
ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

before `ifs.read`. Here is overall code sample that works fine on my machine:

```
int main() {
    double total_bytes, vector_size;
    streampos begin,end;
    std::ifstream ifs("data.dat", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    begin           = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg (0, ios::end);
    end             = ifs.tellg();
    total_bytes     = end - begin; // 320MB, 32e7 
    vector_size     = total_bytes/ sizeof(complex<short>);  // 8e7
    std::cout << vector_size << std::endl;
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    std::vector<std::complex<short>> vs(vector_size);
    std::vector<std::complex<float> > v(vector_size);
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vs.data()), vector_size*sizeof(complex<short>));
    std::copy(vs.begin(), vs.end(), v.begin());
    ifs.close();

    for(int i=0;i<vector_size; i++){
        std::cout <<i << v[i]<< std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's very kind of you, now I understand how to read binary data and make it work. Again, thank you very very much for your helps and supports. Best regards, Khong Long.